# Adjectives that can be used with the noun "need" to express how great the need is

Tags: adjectives, writing-style

I would like to compile a list of adjectives that can be used with the word "need", as in

> In Country X there is [adjective] need of new methods to involve adults in learning activities

and the adjective expressing size (big or small and everything in-between).

Some adjectives that seem to be in use

- considerable
- extraordinary
- inconsiderable
- little

Others would probably sound odd: big, huge, large, vast, tremendous, enormous... at least as long as I do not want to do creative writing but rather write a standard text in an educated institutional context (here: a grant application for an international cooperation in the EU).

This is about good style, including precision and variation of expression.

Suggestions?

Comment: The notion of "size" is usually expressed, in relation to "need," by "great.

Comment: In formal language also? Or rather in informal oral communication?

Comment: My intuition tells me that in  (formal and informal) speech and writing we are much more likely to  use "great" with "need" than "big."

Answer (score 1):

There are adjectives that express "how great" a need is, or the "degree" to which something is needed.  In practice the distinction amounts to one of nuance.

Here is a non-exhaustive list of typical adjectival collocates of "need"  that match your request.  Any of them could be used for the kind of purpose you mention, though words like *desperate* or *dire* obviously need to be used carefully in order not to sound as if you are exaggerating.

"In country X there is:"

*a **great** need for** /
*an **urgent** need for* / 
a **desperate** need for / 
a **dire** need for /
an *as yet **unmet** need for* /
an **immediate** need for /
a **pressing** need for /
*a **critical** need for*

Alternative phrasing would be: "Country X is:"

in **great** need of /
in **urgent** need of /
in **desperate** need of /
in **immediate** need of / 
in **dire** need of

Comment: Would "ardent need" also be an acceptable combination?

Comment: Not to me.  I don't think I have ever come across this combination.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've come across "a burning need for" but not in the kind of context you mention.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ardent%20need%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann   To answer this kind of question about collocations a corpus is the best resource.  As we've just seen the results can often be counter-intuitive.  The web is a rough corpus, and as we have just seen, a good place to start.  I went further, to SketchEngine.co.uk and compared, in a massive and consciously compiled corpus called EnTenTen 2013, , "burning need for" and ardent need for,"  The latter appeared 49 times, the former over 1000 times.  So it looks like a matter of style.  I suspect that "ardent need" will raise eyebrows from many.